# Force spring test configuration to load before main

Tags: java, spring

I have a spring configuration class in main that creates redis client bean.
In tests I have another configuration class which creates embedded redis server bean. The problem is to force embedded redis server bean to be created before redis client one. I tried with @Order anotation without success. Importing test configuration to main one isn't an option.
When I define EmbeddedRedis as @Component then it will be created before the client but this is also not an option since EmbeddedRedis is a part of shareable test library which should not be created when not needed.

I have a workaround solution with an interface called RedisServerConfiguration which has different implementations for main and test and client depends on it so I am able to start server before the client tries to connect but this requires another abstraction and it would be nice to simplify it. Is there any spring mechanism I am not aware of that allows to force the order of bean initialization ?

Comment: I think you could use *@Order* annotation to set configuration priority. Or, there are set of special annotation in *SpringBoot*, like *@DependsOn*.

Comment: Thanks for your hints but DependsOn won't work since I can't make a bean from main to depend on test configuration. @Order like I wrote is not working.